# change activity with JavaScript in Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity

I have an app that should call an activity when a JavaScript is fired,

this is my JavaScript which is working

javascript interface

```
private class JsInterface{
    //function that will be called from assets/test.js
     
    public void log(String msg){
        Log.d("MSG FROM JAVASCRIPT", msg);
                
    }
```

and this is how I call an activity with the touch of a button:

```
 Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), VideoVC.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
```

but as I'm quite noob on Android dev can't figure out how to change the activity on my JsInterface

I have tried in my JSinterface:

```
 Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(JsExampleMain.this, VideoVC.class);
startActivity(myIntent2);
```

but doesn't like the "startActicity(myIntent2);"

how to do this simple task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so i have figure it out!,
haha was making me go crazy!

so i just had to place the code for the Intent inside my log method!

> ```
>   //javascript interface
>      private class JsInterface{
>    //function that will be called from assets/test.js
>     public void log(String msg){
>         Log.d("MSG FROM JAVASCRIPT", msg);
>         Log.d("kukusha", "mensaje");
>         Intent i = new Intent(JsExampleMain.this,VideoVC.class);    
>         startActivity(i); 
>     }
>  }
> ```