# Android HTML5 local mp3

Tags: android, html, mp3

Anyone know for sure if playing local mp3 file using HTML5 is possible or not in Android?
Playing mp3 files from url's works fine, but not when embedded in the app. Been searching for definitive answer.

Thanks for any help

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Player</title>

</head>
<body>
<br /> <br />

     <audio id="player" autoplay loop controls="controls">
    <source src="bassscales.mp3"   />
     </audio>

<br /> <br /> 

<div> 
<button style="width:85;height:75" button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button> 

<button style="width:85;height:75" button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button> 

<button style="width:85;height:75" button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause(); document.getElementById('player').currentTime = 0;">Stop</button>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with HTML5 and `<video>` tag, video playing fine if called programatically from file system, but when called from the tag, didn't work,

the way I solved it is having a javascript function in the HTML call the android system, in your case for playing an mp3

[Android JavaScriptInterface tutorial](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/android-javascriptinterface-tutorial.html)

also check my  [question in the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595761/change-activity-with-javascript-in-android)

note that you need to place in the correct folder the mp3 [sorry don't remember in which folder, make a search and find it easy]

so first do a hello world javascript calling a log or basic function in android,

then make the javascript call the play function,

good luck

ps.
[playing mp3 from assets folder example](http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=272)

and calling Android methods with javascript
[jsInterface example](https://github.com/scottagarman/Android-JavaScript-Interface-Example)

Comment: Can you please share with me the javascript function in HTML call the android system? thanks so much, driving me crazy! :)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am very new to this...I am actually using an activity that opens a webView to display HTML5 document...was hoping this HTML5 audio player could play local files from the same folder :(

Comment: yes thats good, just remember the mp3 should be placed in the assets folder as the mp3 is played by android, the html js is just a call to the android player, check edit for example to play an mp3 from assets folder,

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with me, the main problem is that I am not familiar with the .java code that is opening the HTML document. here is the link to the .java file if you wouldn't mind seeing what u think...thanks!   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/BT_screen_htmlDoc.java

Comment: please check edit, i included a link with sample project, up-vote if useful ;)

Comment: up-vote says need reputation of 15...I will look at the examples and see if I can make sense...will report back thanks!

Comment: still having trouble figuring out how/where this would fit into my existing code... wondering also if caching the streaming mp3 that does play is an easier option? when I leave the html screen and come back the mp3 file needs to redownload to play again...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Does this look correct for the HTML file?

```
<body>

<video id="video"  controls height="270" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/intro1girl.mp4" width="480">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  MyAndroid.video.play();
},false);
</script>
```

then don't know what to put in the JavaScriptInterface.java class...thanks for all the help :)